# How to keep top of element static while bottom is dynamic. -CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown that lists a user's accounts. The list has to be dynamic because the user can have up to ten accounts. My implementation right now makes the div get bigger when adding an account but it gets bigger on top when I want it to get bigger on bottom. Here our some scree shots

This is where the top of the element should be:

[image]

After creating another plan

[image]

As you can see the dropdown is now to tall for its environment. I want this effect to happen but the top should stay static and the bottom should get bigger. Here is my markup and CSS

### HTML

```
<div class="project-background">
      <%= link_to "", "#projects-dropdown", class: "icon icon-project" %>
    </div>
    <% if current_user.accounts.any? %>
      <%= link_to snitches_path, class: "topbar-team__name" do %>
        <span class="topbar-team__name__text"><%= current_account.name %></span>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <div id="projects-dropdown" class="dropdown hidden">
      <h3>Projects</h3>
      <% if current_user.accounts.any? %>
      <ul>
        <% current_user.accounts.each do |account| %>
        <li>
          <%= link_to account.name, switch_account_path(account), class: current_account.id == account.id ? "current-account" : "" %>
        </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to "✚ New Project", new_account_path, class: "button button--invitation" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

### CSS

```
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -179px;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 205px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #cbcbcb;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #cbcbcb;
  background-color: rgb(249, 249, 249);

  &:after,
  &:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 5px;
    border: solid 10px transparent;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
    content: "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Try positioning your `.dropdown` with `top: 30px` (or whatever an appropriate value for `top` is) rather than `bottom` that will make it stick to the top and grow dynamically to the bottom

Comment: As @Dymos:  remove `bottom: -179px;` and replace with `top:30px`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the problem is with this line `bottom: -179px;`

whatever you add in that dropdown element. Its position will be calculated from the bottom. so bottom will be fixed in this condition and element will increase in top direction. So try to convert positioning from `bottom` to `top`